# Only insert unique rows using Linq2SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I do not want to insert duplicate rows in the database, so I check whether the row already exists:

```
foreach (var key in someCollection)
{
    var myObject = dataContext.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(my => my.SomeKey == key);
    if (myObject == null)
    {
        myObject = new MyObject()
        {
            SomeKey = key,
            ...
        };
        dataContext.InsertOnSubmit(myObject);
    }
}
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

However, the query does not find the objects which were already added using InsertOnSubmit, but which are not yet submitted using SubmitChanges. This means that the table still contains duplicate rows. How do I insert every object only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something with the change set if you didn't want to change your code.  You should check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.inserts.aspx

```
dataContext.GetChangeSet().Inserts
```

But I think it'd be better to attack the problem a little differently.  Something like this maybe:

```
Dictionary<object,MyObject> objectsToInsert = new Dictionary<object, MyObject>();
foreach (object key in someCollection)
{
    var myObject = dataContext.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(my => my.SomeKey == key);
    if ((myObject == null) && (objectsToInsert.ContainsKey(key) == false))
    {
        myObject = new MyObject()
        {
            SomeKey = key,
            ...
        };
        objectsToInsert.Add(key,myObject);
    }
}
dataContext.InsertAllOnSubmit(objectsToInsert.Values);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```